# Product of Borel sigma algebras

Tags: measure-theory, fa.functional-analysis

If $X$ and $Y$ are separable metric spaces, then the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $B(X \times  Y)$ of the product is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $B(X)\times B(Y)$.  I am embarrassed to admit that I don't know the answers to:

Question 1. What is a counterexample when $X$ and $Y$ are non-separable?

Question 2. If $X$ is an uncountable discrete metric space, does
$B(X) \times B(X)$ generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $X \times X$?

Question  3. If $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces, with $X$ separable, does
$B(X) \times B(Y)$ generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $X \times Y$?

Comment: In 2011 Todorcevic (see "Embedding function spaces into $l_\infty/c_0$", J. Math. Anal. Appl. 384, 2011, pg. 246–251) found a connection between Question 2 for $|X|=\mathfrak{c}$ and the universality of the space $l_\infty/c_0$. But perhaps you already knew this since your question precedes the paper.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Q1.  Discrete spaces with cardinal > c ... then the diagonal is a Borel set, but not in the product sigma-algebra.

This also answers Q2 (no)

but not Q3.

Comment: I think he does mean $>c$. The assertion being made is exercise 29 in the Radon measures chapter of Folland's real analysis text.

Comment: Thanks, Jerry & Keenan.  Simple but nice. 

What is the answer to Q2 when $X$ has cardinality the continuum?

Comment: If $X$ is of size $c$, say $X=\mathbb R$, then the complement of the diagonal in $X^2$ is the union of countably many rectangles.
This follows from the fact that $\mathbb R^2$ has a countable basis for the topology consisting of rectangles.  Now, we are interested
in the discrete topology on $X$, but the fact remains, 
the diagonal in $X^2$ is in the product $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Of course, this does not show that the product $\sigma$-algebra is the same as the $\sigma$-algebra on the product.  It just shows that the diagonal does not distinguish the two algebras.

Comment: Here is an accesible proof: http://david.efnet-math.org/?p=16

Comment: Similar to, but IMO a bit better than, Folland's proof, Michael. Thanks for the reference.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker  that accessible proof link is defunct.

Answer (score 21):

The answer to question 3 is yes. 
At least according to Lemma 6.4.2 of the second volume of Bogachev's book "Measure Theory".

He requires both spaces to be Hausdorff and one of them to have a countable base. 
They need not be metric spaces.

Comment: Oh, yes, Byron.  This is simple enough that this simpleton should have seen the argument.  Thanks, and sorry that I can only accept one answer.

Comment: No problem. I really didn't do anything except follow my own advice: when you have an "unusual" measure theory question, try looking in Bogachev. His book is an impressive achievement.   

Comment: Yes, it is very nice.  I had never looked at it before reading your answer.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 13):

To close a gap: From the answer of Gerald Edgar, we know that the answer to the second question is no if the spaces involved have cardinality larger than $\mathfrak{c}$. This leaves open what happens when they *do* have cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$. The answer is yes under the continuum hypothesis, and in general it holds that $2^{\omega_1}\otimes 2^{\omega_1}=2^{\omega_1\times\omega_1}$. This was shown in

B. V. Rao, [On discrete Borel spaces and projective sets](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-75/issue-3/On-discrete-Borel-spaces-and-projective-sets/bams/1183530570.full)
Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. Volume 75, Number 3 (1969), 614-617.

In Bogachev's remarkable book, it can be found as Proposition 3.10.2.

Answer (score 10):

This is should probably rather be a comment to Michael Greinecker's answer, but I do not have the necessary privileges.

Michael Greinecker's answer leaves open what happens with a continuum-sized discrete space when one does *not* assume the continuum hypothesis.

Arnold W. Miller showed in section 4 of [On the length of Borel hierarchies](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~miller/res/hier.pdf) that it is consistent relative ZFC that no universal analytic set $U \subset [0,1] \times [0,1]$ belongs to the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{P}[0,1] \otimes \mathcal{P}[0,1]$. Combined with Rao's result mentioned by Michael Greinecker, this shows that $2^{\mathfrak{c \times c}} = 2^{\mathfrak{c}} \otimes 2^\mathfrak{c}$ is independent of ZFC.

See my answer to [Universally measurable sets of $\mathbb{R}^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/177416) on math.stackexchange.com for related results and more details and references.

Comment: K. Kunen in his doctoral dissertation (1968) proved that adding more than continuum many Cohen reals always gives a model where $2^{\mathfrak{c \times c}} \neq 2^{\mathfrak{c}} \otimes 2^\mathfrak{c}$.