# Comparing two $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Let $X$ be a set. We denote $P(X)$ by the family of all subsets of $X$. We also denote $P(X)\otimes_{\sigma}P(X)$ by the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\{A\times B: A,B \subseteq X\}$.

Q.  For which cardinal numbers $\alpha$ the following holds?

$$Card(X)=\alpha \Longrightarrow   P(X\times X)=P(X)\otimes_{\sigma}P(X)$$

Comment: See Question 2 here: https://mathoverflow.net/q/39882/454 and the answer by Michael Greinecker

Comment: @Gerald Edgar: Thanks. Is it  unknown when $X$ has  cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$ yet?

Comment: See Martin's answer to the same post.