# Basic properties of expectation in non-separable Banach spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, banach-spaces

$\def\E{\hskip.15ex\mathsf{E}\hskip.10ex}$
Let $B$ be a (maybe nonseparable) Banach space equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{B}(B)$. Let $R:B\to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded linear operator.

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space. Let $F$ be a $\mathscr{B}(B)|\mathcal{F}$-measurable mapping $\Omega\to B$. Suppose that $\E \|F\|<\infty$.

Question: is it true without any additional assumptions that $\E F$ is well-defined, belongs to $B$ and
$$
\E RF= R \E F?
$$

Remark: usually (e.g. in the Ledoux-Talagrand book) the separability of the space B is additionally imposed. I wonder whether the statement is true without this assumption. For example, what happens if $B$ is just a space of bounded measurable functions (in that case one can just define $[\E F](x):=\E[F(x)]$)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\newcommand{\E}{\operatorname{\mathsf{E}}}$
You do not need the separability of $B$ to define $\E F$ for a random vector $F\colon\Omega\to B$; however, you need to assume that $F$ is strongly measurable, in the sense that there is a sequence of finitely-valued random vectors $F_n$ in $B$ such that $\|F_n(\omega)-F(\omega)\|\to0$ for almost all $\omega\in\Omega$.

By Bochner's theorem, if $F$ is strongly measurable, then $\E\|F\|<\infty$ iff $F$ is Bochner-integrable, in the sense that for some sequence of finitely-valued random vectors $F_n$ in $B$ we have $\|F_n(\omega)-F(\omega)\|\to0$ for almost all $\omega$ and $\E\|F_n-F\|\to0$; then $\E F:=\lim_n\E F_n$, with naturally defined $\E F_n$.

It is then known and easy to check that $\E RF=R\E F$ for any strongly measurable random vector $F$ with $\E\|F\|<\infty$ and any bounded linear operator $R\colon B\to\mathbb R$; that is, the Bochner integrability implies the Pettis integrability.

See e.g. [Yosida, Sections V.4 and V.5](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642962080) for further details.

---

Concerning your remark that usually the Banach space is assumed to be separable: this is done to ensure the measurability in a number of instances, including the measurability of the sum of random vectors.

Comment: Iosif, thanks a lot for a detailed answer. Do you know if the same would be true for conditional expectations: if $F$ is strongly measurable with $E\|F\|<\infty$, $\mathcal{G}$ is a sub-$\sigma$-algebra, then $E(F|\mathcal{G})$ is well-defined and strongly measurable?

Comment: Also I wonder about the case when $B$ is the space of bounded functions on, say, $[0,1]$. If $F$ is not strongly measurable (just measurable), can it happen that the function $x\to EF(x)$ is not measurable?

Comment: Also I am a bit puzzled about your last comment: if $F$, $G$ are measurable, isn't it always true that $F+G$ is measurable? Is there a counterexample?

Comment: $F$, $G$ measruable need not imply $F+G$ measurable in the nonseparable case.  See https://mathoverflow.net/a/313792/454

Comment: @Oleg : I don't know answers, right away, to your additional questions, on the conditional expectation and $EF(x)$, but can try to think about them. In this case and in general, I believe it's best, in more aspects than one, to post the additional questions separately.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar : Thank you for the reference to the nice counterexample.

Comment: @Oleg : I have now given an (affirmative) answer https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338270/conditional-expectation-of-random-vectors/338271#338271 to your additional question concerning the conditional expectation.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

A counterexample for random variable with nonseparable range.

Let $\omega_1$ be the smallest uncountable ordinal.  Let $\Omega = [0,\omega_1)$, the set of countable ordinals, with the order topology.  Then the Banach space $B = C[0,\omega_1)$ will be used.  Note: every real-avalued continuous function on $[0,\omega_1)$ is bounded.  Moreover, 
$$
\lim_{\alpha \to \omega_1} f(\alpha)
$$
exists for every $f \in B$ and
$\phi : B \to \mathbb R$ defined by
$$
\phi(f) = \lim_{\alpha \to \omega_1} f(\alpha)
$$
is a bounded linear functional.
[The Stone-Cech compactification of $\Omega$ is the one-point compactification of $\Omega$.]

Our measure space is $(\Omega,\mathcal F, \mathbb P)$, where $\mathcal F$ is the countable-cocountable sigma-algebra, and $\mathbb P$ is $0$ on countable sets and $1$ on cocountable sets.  Note: if $f \in C[0,\omega_1)$, then the integral is
$$
\int f(\alpha)\;\mathbb P(d\alpha) = \lim_{\alpha \to \omega_1} f(\alpha) = \phi(f) .
$$

Define $F : \Omega \to B$ by $F(\alpha) = \mathbf1_{(\alpha,\omega_1)} $, the indicator function of the interval $(\alpha,\omega_1)$, which is a clopen set.

We will show that that there is no $\mathbb E[F] \in B$ with the property $\mathbb E[R\circ F] = R\big(\mathbb E[F]\big)$ for all bounded linear functionals $R : B \to \mathbb R$.  Suppose it does exist.

Fix $\xi \in [0,\omega_1)$.  Then $f \mapsto f(\xi)$ is a bounded linear functional, and
$$
F(\alpha)(\xi) = \begin{cases}
1,\quad \alpha < \xi
\\
0,\quad \alpha \ge \xi
\end{cases}
$$
and thus
$$
0 = \lim_{\alpha \to \omega_1} F(\alpha)(\xi) =
\int F(\alpha)(\xi)\;\mathbb P(d\alpha) =
\left(\mathbb E[F]\right)(\xi)
$$
This holds for all $\xi$ so $\mathbb E[F] = \mathbf 0$, the zero element of $B$.

On the other hand $\phi$ defined above is a bounded linear functional, and
$$
\phi(F(\alpha)) = \lim_{\xi \to \omega_1}F(\alpha)(\xi) = 1
$$
for all $\alpha$.

So
$$
\mathbb E[\phi\circ F] =\int\phi(F(\alpha))\;\mathbb P(d\alpha)
=\int 1\;\mathbb P(d\alpha) = 1 .
$$
This is not equal to $\phi\big(\mathbb E[F]\big) = \phi(\mathbf 0) = 0$.

.....

Now I'm wondering if $F$ is Borel.

Comment: Gerald, thanks for this interesting counter-example. Do you think something similar can happen if $B$ is a space of bounded Borel measurable functions?